# Office Add-In registry settings on Citrix installation

Tags: windows-installer, registry, vsto

I have implemented a VSTO add-in in .Net, and have a question concerning its deployment and registry settings.
In the following [Microsoft link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it says that the MSI installer should create keys in either HKCU or HKLM depending on whether we want the add-in to be used by only the person installing or all users on the machine.

Does that mean that on a Citrix installation, we should only create the keys under HKLM, because otherwise it will only be the installer of the add-in who can see the add-in and use it?

Actually we have a customer who wants to create differentiated LoadBehavior per user, because some users are not authorized to use the add-in. To do this, the admin deleted the LoadBehavior key from HKLM, and created a grouppolicy that is activated when a user logs in. So if the user is a memeber of the AD-group, then that user gets the add-in Keys under his HKCU with LoadBehavior = 3. If the user is not a memeber, the same happens but LoadBehavior = 2.

My question is, is there any way I can support our customer with this, through the MSI we send to them? Currently the MSI only creates Keys in HKLM, but I see no sense in also creating the keys in HKCU, because that will only be for the user installing the add-in, or what?

My other question is that my MSI has an option whether to install the add-in for "All Users" or "Just me". How is that choice reflected in the above registry settings? Or is it merely a way to restrict access to the binaries of the add-in?

I hope the above questions are clear enough.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I don't work with Application-level Add-Ins, but I'm familiar enough with Add-In installation to feel qualified to answer this.

1. Yes
2. I think using LoadBehavior for this is not the intended purpose. Instead it seems to be there to deal with Add-Ins that cause problems, crash, etc. It seems fallible to use it this way because users can try to enable it, unless that is also locked down (I don't know if enabling add-ins can be controlled via GPO, but a cursory google search suggests the answer is Yes). If they don't need a 100% perfect solution, or have these other controls in place, it may suffice to install to HKLM.
3. The difference between All Users and Just Me is probably the difference between HKLM and HKCU, but the answer can probably be found in documentation. You could also just try it and find out.